# The size of tensor a (70) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to put a tensor at the training model, but it's returning this error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
The size of tensor a (70) must match the size of tensor b (10) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

I'd try to change the criterion, but the error persists

Importantly Code:
training_input = torch.FloatTensor(x[:70])
training_output = torch.FloatTensor(y[:70])

```
input_size = training_input.size()[1]
hidden_size = 10
model = Net(input_size, hidden_size)

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 0.09, 0.03)

for param in model.parameters():
    pass

model.train()
epochs = 100
errors = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  # Fazer o forward
  y_pred = model(training_input)
  loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), training_output)
  errors.append(loss.item())
  if epoch % 1000 == 0:
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}. Train loss: {loss.item()}.')
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```